# Man page to PDF with groff: no space after headings

Tags: groff

I have written a 250+ page manual page whose printed appearance I'm trying to polish. It uses the old-style `man` macros: the page begins with `.TH`, and uses things like `.SH`, `.SS` and `.TP` for sectioning.

The ugly problem is that there is no space between these headings, and between headings and text.

If I put a blank line between `.TP` and the paragraph, then I get one in the output. I don't want to do that! Secondly, this workaround doesn't work between the headings. For instance:

```
.SH Foo
.SS Bar
.TP Xyzzy
blah blah

blah blah
```

looks a lot like this:

```
Foo
  Bar
    Xyzzy
      blah blah

      blah blah
```

There is space between paragraphs, but almost none between the headings. This is okay for `nroff` formatting when the man page is viewed online, but horrible in print.

I've pored over the `groff` macro internals but don't see any obvious way of adjusting this behavior without rewriting these macros.

I also don't understand how an arbitrary number of blank lines are being eaten between section requests. That is:

```
.SH Foo



.SS Bar



.TP Xyzzy

blah blah

blah blah
```

produces:

```
Foo
  Bar
    Xyzzy

      blah blah

      blah blah
```

Only the blank line after `.TP` did anything. This means that if I make a macro `.mySS` which naively just expands to `.SS` and a blank line, I'm guessing that it won't work.

Using blank lines (and, generally, compounded whitespace) for influencing layout is hacky anyway; it's rather sad that it even has an effect at all after `.TP`.

Comment: Try `.sp` to add a blank line. `.sp 2` will add 2, `.sp 0.3i` will add 0.3 inches, etc.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I see; if I fold that into wrappers like `.mySH`, `.mySS` and `.myTP`, that should do it.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Aha, you pushed me in the right direction. I also discovered the `.ns` request and that has lead me to get a better idea of how Groff's `SS` and others "eat" blank lines. `SS` sets a one-line trap which points to a generic macro `an-trap` used as a common trap various constructs. It also sets a global flag `an-no-space-flag` which the `an-trap` checks; if the flag is set, it invokes `.ns`.  This is also the reason why `.sp` doesn't work by itself! The "no-space mode" that eats lines. But it works if `.sp ARG` is preceded by `.rs` to cancel no space mode.

Comment: Good job. I forgot all about `.ns`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I've wrapped my head around this now. I even have `.ie n ... .el` stuff to do things differently for nroff and troff. Also, all the sections and subsections of the page now have automatic section numbers. Plus, I've developed about fifteen patches to the `man2html` program from the `man-1.6g` package. It can now handle complex macros, groff-style `.while` loops and more. Code can test that it can run under `man2html` now by checking for nonzero in the `.m2` reg. There is a `.M2SS` request for generating arbitary-level subsections with a custom HTML tag.